# Can you mutate an object in R and still maintain its identity

Tags: python, r

In python you can do the following:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a 
a.append(3)
print(a)
#[1,2,3]
print(b)
#[1,2,3]
```

I am new to R. I haven't seen any situation yet where you can change an object without assignment operation.

Comment: It is possible to do this in R, and there are some functions that do it, but R is essentially a procedural / functional language. This means that functions which change the input variables without explicit assignment are generally avoided. Those that do are normally written in such a way that they _look_ like assignment operators. For example, when you write `a[3] <- 2`, this is actually interpreted by the parser as a call to a function called  `[<-` which modifies its input variable.

Comment: Thanks. I found this paper that discusses object identity in R 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229087107_Prototype-Based_Programming_in_Statistical_Computation